# How can I get detailed error messages from a pure function in D?

Tags: d

In D, suppose I have a function like:

```
 private static double vecMult(immutable Vector v1, immutable Vector v2) pure {
                double sum = 0.0;
                foreach(ulong k; v1.keys)
                        sum += v1[k] * v2[k];
                return sum;
 }
```

Now, suppose, for debugging or testing purposes, I would like to insert something like:

```
 private static double vecMult(immutable Vector v1, immutable Vector v2) pure {
                double sum = 0.0;
                foreach(ulong k; v1.keys)
                        if(!(k in v2)){
                                writeln(k);
                                exit(1);
                        }
                        sum += v1[k] * v2[k];
                return sum;
 }
```

so that, if an error condition happens, I have some idea of what caused it ( I can always put this in a debug block later).

Now, since writeln is not pure, vecMult is no longer pure either. If vecMult is a low level function that is called by other pure functions, that call other pure functions, then removing the "pure" keyword from vecMult is non-trivial.

Is there a nice way to obtain debugging output from a pure function without making it non-pure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `debug` blocks to bypass purity in `pure` functions. Example:

```
 private static double vecMult(immutable Vector v1, immutable Vector v2) pure {
                double sum = 0.0;
                foreach(ulong k; v1.keys) {
                        debug if(!(k in v2)){
                                writeln(k);
                                exit(1);
                        }
                        sum += v1[k] * v2[k];
                }
                return sum;
 }
```

Remember to build your program with the `-debug` compiler switch to enable `debug` blocks.

Comment: Walter wrote a [short article](http://www.drdobbs.com/tools/implementing-pure-functions/230700070) about this feature.

Comment: Thanks. Glad to see there's a nice solution to this.

Comment: @eco That article is quite good. Future readers of this answer beware however: the function will still be optimized as though it were pure, so the debug contents will be executed only when the function is called, not when a cached result is accessed/used.

Comment: Another option would be to pass it some kind of log accumulator as a parameter. As long as it isn't passed `immutable`, the function will be able to write to it (`pure` in D limits the scope of access the function has to the parameters only, it doesn't require all parameters actually be immutable). But for debugging, the `debug writeln` is by far the easiest.